# I installed wordpress on ubuntu, but as I run "sudo su", then "cd /var/www" then "ls", I see there is no wordpress directory. How can I solve this?

Tags: command-line, apache2, wordpress, url

I installed WordPress on Ubuntu according to the website https://www.journaldev.com/24954/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu, and I am now trying to find the URL of the website. For that, I am following this video's instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HEfJsAoTrY. However, as I run "sudo su", then "cd /var/www" then "ls" on the command line, I see there is no WordPress directory. Then, after running "cd etc/apache2" this message appears:
bash: cd: etc/apache2: No such file or directory.
How can I fix this problem so as to find my URL?
Thank you

Comment: 1. where did you install wordpress. Oh and see `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for the contents of the files there. It should point to the dir. 2. there has to be a `/` in front of `etc`.

Comment: @Rinzwind The / solved the problem. Thank you very much! I am not sure where I installed WordPress, as I just followed the step by step of the website...